# Select box not refreshing on emptying, then adding back options

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1088/).

I have a text box and as the user type keys in the box, the `multiple select` box must refresh its options.

On `input change`, I am using this code to refresh `select options`,

```
$("select").empty()  
 filteredOpts.map(function(val){
        $("select").append("<option name={0} value={0}>{0}</option>".format(val))
})
```

But, the view is not getting refreshed with new set of options.

When i move to some screen, (for example, pressing `ctrl + shift + c` to open chrome console) the view gets refreshed. Same behavior is seen in firefox too where the select box doesn't show the filtered options, but when i go to `firebug` console and come back, the select box has refreshed its options.

Comment: the `change` event is triggered when the focus is lost on text inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're *only* handling the Change event and not the Input event like you say you are. The Change event only fires after the element is blurred.

Change:

```
$("body").on("change", "#pattern", textChange)
```

To:

```
$("body").on("input change", "#pattern", textChange)
```

(You can probably drop the Change event altogether from that, too).

[**Working JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/JfGVE/1089/).

Answer (score 2):

change event will be fired when you focus out of the text box.use `keyup` event instead `change` try this `$("body").on("keyup", "#pattern", textChange)` .